# Summernote only works when refreshed

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

So Im very new to Javascript and I just installed Summernote text editor. I can get the text editor to work only when I hit refresh on the page. Ive watched and read a couple different tutorials but still no fix.

This is my post.coffee

```
$ ->
 ready = ->
   $('[data-provider="summernote"]').each ->
   $(this).summernote()

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

And this is where I have the text editor popup on my _form.html.erb

```
  <%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :body, as: :summernote %>
  <% end %>
```

Again I can get it to work but I have to hit refresh every time. Im using Rails 5 if that means anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `turbolinks`, you can change your code like below.

```
$ ->
  document.addEventListener 'turbolinks:load', ->
    $('[data-provider="summernote"]').each ->
      $(this).summernote()
```

Documentation is [here](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#running-javascript-when-a-page-loads). I hope this help you.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much!